# explicit - практическое применение

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

Принцип работы конструкторов с ключевым словом `explicit` понял.
В чем заключается практическое применение?

Если мы хотим "огородиться" от нежелательных (нам) преобразований, то:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int val) {
        cout << "A(int)" << endl;
    }

    A(char* val) {
        cout << "A(char*)" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a = 'x';

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат будет: "A(int)"
Если мы пометим оба конструктора `explicit` в целях "ограждения", то при:
`A a('x');` мы все равно получим результат выше. Все равно произойдет ненужное (нам) преобразование.

Comment: А что не так? Char скорее скастуется к int (и то и то целое цисло по факту) чем к указателю.

Comment: Иногда бывает так, что без `explicit` для компилятора возникает двусмысленная ситуация и код не скомпилируется.

Answer (score 16):

Он нужен не столько для того, чтобы вызывать конкретный конструктор, сколько для того, чтобы не было ненужного приведения типов (или приведение было однозначным).

Грубо - представим, что конструктор `vector` от `int` - **не** `explicit`. И у нас есть

```
void f(vector<>...);
```

Тогда вызов `f(5)` тоже будет вполне допустимой конструкцией. Вряд ли это кому-то нужно... Как и

```
vector v;
v = 5;
```

Кстати, Страуструп пишет, что было бы неплохо, если бы все конструкторы по умолчанию были `explicit`, и явно надо было указывать отказ он него.

Примерно так.

Answer (score 12):

Конструктор без `explicit` позволяет осуществлять неявное преобразование типа аргумента в тип класса, которому принадлежит конструктор.

> Если мы пометим оба конструктора explicit в целях "ограждения", то при: A a('x'); мы все равно получим результат выше.

Правильно, потому что запись `A a('x');` есть [*direct-initialization*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#16), для которой [как раз подходит](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#2) `explicit` конструктор. Т.е. здесь есть неявное преобразование типа `char` в тип `int` для аргумента, но вот преобразование в тип `A` уже вполне явное.

> В чем заключается практическое применение?

Неявные преобразования опасная вещь, с одной стороны они позволяют писать меньше *буков кода*, с другой - можно получить не совсем то, чего ожидаешь. Т.е. глядя на код видим одно, а в процессе выполнения происходит несколько иное, т.к. неявное преобразование происходит, как это ни странно, неявно.

Например, в ситуации с уже упомянутым `std::vector`, конструктор, принимающий целое, помечен как `explicit`, т.к. это целое задает размер, хотя непосвященный пользователь ожидал бы от записи `std::vector<int> v = 5;` скорее помещения числа `5` в вектор, но уж точно не создания вектора из пяти элементов, инициализированных нулями. Но к счастью, `explicit` не дает такой записи скомпилироваться.

Дополнительно хочу отметить, что до `c++11` `explicit` актуально было делать только конструкторы, которые можно вызывать с одним аргументом. С появлением *uniform initialization* это стало актуальным и для конструкторов, требующих нескольких обязательных аргументов. Например:

```
struct A {
    /* explicit */ A(int, double, char) {}
};

A f() { 
    return {42, 1.5, 'a'}; 
}

int main() {
    A a = {1, 2.0, 'b'};
}
```

работает пока нет `explicit`. Если сделать конструктор явным, код придется изменить:

```
A f() { 
    return A{42, 1.5, 'a'}; 
}

int main() {
    A a = A{1, 2.0, 'b'}; 
    // или A a{1, 2.0, 'b'}; // direct initialization
}
```

---

Кстати, хотя в вопросе упомянуты только конструкторы, `explicit` может быть применен также и к операторам преобразования (начиная с `c++11`):

```
struct A {
    explicit operator int() { return 42; }
};

int main() {
    A a;

    int j = a; // (1)
    int i = static_cast<int>(a); // (2)

    bool b = a; // (3)

    if(a) { // (4)
        // do something 
    }
    else {
        // do another 
    }
}
```

Если `operator int` не помечен как `explicit`, то весь код полностью работоспособен. Когда добавляем `explicit`, только строка `(2)` остается валидной. Немного особенным в данном случае будет смотреться `operator bool()` вместо `operator int()`:

```
struct A {
    explicit operator bool() { return true; }
};
```

При `explicit` операторе будет работать только строка `(4)`, т.к. использование переменной в условных выражениях (`if`, `while`, `?:`) интерпретируется как **явное** преобразование к `bool`. Без `explicit` код по-прежнему полностью работоспособен.

Answer (score 7):

В дополнение к ответу @Harry, и как разворот своего комментария:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    operator int() const 
    { 
        return 42; 
    }
};

class Bar 
{ 
public:
    Bar(Foo) 
    {

    } 
};

void baz(Bar)
{

}

void baz(int)
{

}

int main()
{
    Foo x;
    baz(x);
}
```

Вызов функции `baz` здесь приведет к неопределенности для компилятора, т.к. он попадает под оба варианта `baz(int)` и `baz(Bar)`. Добавление `explicit` к конструктору `Bar` даст компилятору однозначное указание к выбору функции.