# Неправильный выбор конструктора

Tags: c++

Почему эта программа выводит `doubledouble`, я же явно указываю `int`?!

```
struct A {
    explicit A(int) {
        std::cout << "int";
    };

    A(double) {
        std::cout << "double";
    };
};


int main() {
    A a1 = 42;
    A a2 = int(42);
}
```

Comment: Между a1 и a2 вообще никакой разницы нет. И [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547797/176217) немного об `explicit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя синтаксис [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) вы как раз явно указываете не использовать `explicit` конструктор. Для вызова `explicit` конструктора следует использовать синтаксис [direct list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
a1{42};
A a2{int{42}};
// выводится intint
```